# lifecycle hook diagram

Tags: vue.js

Is this [instance lifecycle hooks diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) also valid(the same) for a vue.js **single file component** or a **global component(`vue.componnet()`)**? or is it only used for a Vue instance(new Vue)??

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these lifecycle hooks are there for all vue instances: SFCs, global components, explicit `new Vue`, vue-test-utils wrappers, and so on.

The only thing that SFC do are to write the `.render` method for you because it's way simpler to write it with an html-like syntax rather than write the render function manually.

In an SFC, you'd tap into them as such:

```
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    // do something on created
  }
}
</script>
```

In an explicit `new Vue`, like this:

```js
new Vue({
  created() {
    // do something on created
  }
});
```

You get the point.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I wanted to ask one more thing, when I create an SFC or a global component (vue.component() ), Vue will translate/transpile these components (SFC and global) to a new Vue() call ?

Comment: Yes, that is why the root element of a vue component in the DOM has a `__vue__` property that is an instance of `Vue`